# How to downgrade docker on CoreOS?

Tags: docker, coreos, downgrade

I had my `update-engine.service` service running on my core-os machine and it has upgraded my docker from 1.3 to 1.10 which is causing my docker to fail to start with the following exception:

```
Jun 06 11:50:37 sof2-coreos-01 dockerd[682]: time="2016-06-06T11:50:37.821361858Z" level=error msg="migration failed for 342d116985fbcac660953f23fecb1978aa02174cbaec7dce07164df7
```

I see that this has been seen on docker 1.10 before: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20147

Is there a way I can downgrade my docker back to 1.3?

**PS:** I am running this core-os machine on VMware ESXi and have a snapshot which dates to a state where docker was 1.3, but I am curious to know if there is a way to downgrade docker on core-os.

Comment: Have u tried this already? https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/manual-rollbacks.html

Comment: @Shibashis: That would downgrade the version of coreos I am using. I don't want to do that, I just want to downgrade docker.

Answer (score 1):

The most feasible option is to run Docker 1.3 inside of rkt as described in 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreos-dev/icuel9OveRQ.